# Subtract $sum from Sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following record in my MongoDB table:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a00c1c71680084c55811ae2"),
    "name" : "test",
    "tenantId" : "paul",
    "price" : 300,
    "deposits" : [ 
        {
            "amount" : 100,
            "date" : ISODate("2017-11-07T14:08:19.324Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a01be55424b0f8922a5b472")
        },
        {
            "amount" : 50,
            "date" : ISODate("2017-11-87T14:08:19.324Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a01be55424b0f8922a5b473")
        }
    ],
    "attention" : "",
    "due" : ISODate("2017-10-26T22:00:00.000Z")
}
```

I would like to filter all the records with a specific tenantId, and then subtract the SUM of my amounts in the subdocument.

I found out how to Sum the Subdocument:

```
db.table.aggregate( [
{ $match : { tenantId: "paul" } },
{ $unwind:{ path: "$deposits", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true  }},
{ $group: {
    _id: '$_id', 
    deposits: { $sum: '$deposits.amount' },

} }
```

] );
but when i try to subtract the $sum from $price like

```
 deposits: { $subtract: [ $price , $sum: '$deposits.amount'  ] },
```

than i get an error saying

```
Error: Line 6: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can simply do:

```
db.table.aggregate( [
  { "$match" : { "tenantId": "paul" } },
  //{ $unwind:{ path: "$deposits", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true  }},
  { "$project":
    "deposits": { "$subtract": ["$price", { "$sum": "$deposits.amount" } ] }
  }}
])
```

Since MongoDB 3.2 you can actually [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and an array of arguments ( or an array ) and therefore do not need to `$unwind` at all.

> *Changed in version 3.2: $sum is available in the $group and $project stages. In previous versions of MongoDB, $sum is available in the $group stage only.*
>
> *When used in the $project stage, $sum returns the sum of the specified expression or list of expressions for each document ...*

The "long" way, which is the "old" way is to actually use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), but you would then actually add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) following the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.table.aggregate( [
  { "$match" : { "tenantId": "paul" } },
  { $unwind:{ path: "$deposits", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true  }},
  { "$group":
    "_id": "$_id",
    "price": { "$first": "$price" },
    "deposits": { "$sum": "$deposits.amount" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "deposits": { "$subtract": [ "$price", "$deposits" ] }
  }}
])
```

And of course you then need the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator in order to return the `"price"` field from the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage so it can be used in the following stage.

But if you can do `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`, then you actually have MongoDB 3.2, and therefore are better off using the statement **without** the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) at all, since it's much faster to do it that way.